# Get number of sites deployed under current service plan with Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to display the number of webApps/Sites deployed under the current service plan.  This is what I have so far, cant seem to get it working though. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
$q = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan | Get-Member -name NumberOfSites 
Write-Host $q
```

Comment: `$q = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfSites` ? `Get-Member` is used to get data about the objects/properties like type/class etc., not the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the correct cmdlet but the piped command is wrong. *Get-Member* will tell about the methods and properties of a particular object. So you won't be able to get any values out of it.

Try this:

```
$result = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfSites
Write-host $result
```

Hope it helps.